# Python - how to put some elements of array to other arrays based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `test=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]`, I want to put these elements to three empty lists(list1=[], list2=[], list3=[]) based on the times of index

Expected outcome:`list1=[a, d, g], list2=[b, e, h], list3=[c, f, i]`, indexs for them are `index1=[0,3,6] index2=[1,4,7] index3=[2,5,8]`, actually indexs_list are not defined, I just want to use them to describe the question well

I am kind of have not an idea, could any help?

Comment: Do you want the 'index' lists, too, or are those just to show the relevant index numbers? If you want them, would dictionary structures be appropriate to associate letters with indexes?  Finally, do you want to do this in a generic way that will work for any number of target lists or just to solve this specific example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vanilla python:

```
test=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

my_lists = [[], [], []]
for mod in range(3):
    my_lists[mod] = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(test) if i % 3 == mod]

list0 = my_lists[0]
list1 = my_lists[1]
list2 = my_lists[2]

print(list0, list1, list2)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'd', 'g']
['b', 'e', 'h']
['c', 'f', 'i']
```

Comment: Bear in mind, this solution works only for these specific index lists (and for these specific lists, a simpler solution is possible). In general, this solution does not work.

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

l1,l2,l3=np.array(test).reshape(3,-1, order='F')
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> print(l1,l2,l3)
['a' 'd' 'g'] ['b' 'e' 'h'] ['c' 'f' 'i']
```

Ref:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension shall suffice, though it is not the most efficient solution (iterates through the list three times) and works only if you have a fixed number of index lists:

```
list1, list2, list3 = [[test[i] for i in index ] 
                       for index in (index1, index2, index3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you are beginning with Python.

For this reason I would like to suggest a very simple solution just using Python basics:

```
list_1_indexes = [0,3,6]
list_2_indexes = [1,4,7]
list_3_indexes = [2,5,8]

test=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]

list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []

for index in list_1_indexes:
    list_1.append(test[index])

for index in list_2_indexes:
    list_2.append(test[index])

for index in list_3_indexes:
    list_3.append(test[index])


print("list_1:")
print(list_1)
print("\nlist_2:")
print(list_2)
print("\nlist_3:")
print(list_3)
```

**Output**

```
list_1:
['a', 'd', 'g']

list_2:
['b', 'e', 'h']

list_3:
['c', 'f', 'i']
```